# Should I stop my node-kafka-consumer on offsetOutOfRange?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I wrote a node-kafka consumer. In rare cases, I start the kafka client with a group-id that was used when certain offsets were available, but are not available anymore- causing the "offsetOutOfRange" event to be called.
What is the recommended behaviour in this case? Log error and exit? Is there a way to recover? I always want to run zookeeper from the last committed offset (if exists and available).

```
client = new kafka.Client(ZOOKEEPER_URLS),

consumer = new Consumer(client, [], {
      groupId: GROUP_ID,
      fromOffset: true
    });

consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (topic) {
      applicationLogger.error('Kafka consumer is trying to read from offset which is out of range', topic);
      process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why this is not implemented in node-kafka-consumer, but the default behavior for handling offset out of range errors in other clients is to issue an [OffsetRequest](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-OffsetRequest) to get either the earliest or latest available offset, then set the consumer offset to a new value and continue fetching.

This is a completely recoverable situation and you'll just need to specify what offset you want to recover to - earliest or latest available.